# sql server query on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

There is a table:

```
ID   Name   Rank
1    X       Professor
2    X       Principal
3    X       Term Prof
4    X       assistant
```

What I want is want to write the stored procedure to select the last professor rank or assistant rank depending on the input. Here is the format of the stored proc:

```
create procedure proc_name(@includeassistant varchar(3))

end
```

if includeassistant is "yes" then assistant then the last row must be displayed if include assistant is no then Term prof row must be given.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
create procedure proc_name(@includeassistant varchar(3))
AS
BEGIN
  IF @includeassistant='YES'
     SELECT   * FROM dbo.[table] where [RANK]='assistant'
  ELSE 
     SELECT   * FROM dbo.[table] where [RANK]='Term Prof'
END


--- OR 

create procedure proc_name(@includeassistant varchar(3))
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT   * 
  FROM dbo.[table] 
  WHERE [RANK]=CASE WHEN @includeassistant='YES' THEN 'assistant' ELSE 'Term Prof' END
END
```

Comment: actually there are many types of assistant for example asst1,asst2... so cannot use the case function as it will duplicate the code... is there any other way

Comment: The  you must have some other column  in your table with type   to pull that type of data

Answer (score 1):

I wonder what you mean by "**last** professor rank" but anyway there is no such function as `LAST` in T-SQL.
But you can try this (assuming that `ID` is `IDENTITY`):

```
create procedure proc_name
@includeassistant varchar(3)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT TOP 1 ID, Name, Rank
FROM tbl
WHERE (@includeassistant='YES' AND Rank='Assistant')
      OR (@includeassistant='NO' AND Rank='Professor')
ORDER BY ID DESC
```